# Undefined Meteor user object in a Handlebars template function

Tags: meteor

The following simple function on a template will usually fail on me because the `user` object is undefined, even though I'm logged in:

```
Template.hello.userData = function() {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
  return user.emails[0].address;
};
```

It's easy to duplicate:

- on the command-line:

  - meteor create test-user
  - cd test-user
  - meteor add accounts-password
  - meteor add accounts-ui
- edit test-user.js and add the 'userData' code (above) into the isClient block
- edit test-user.html and add inside 'hello' template: {{loginButtons}} {{userData}}
- go to the app and create an account, which signs you in and you get an error in the console:
      `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined`

The insidious thing is the "usually" part: it sometimes succeeds, so there may be a race condition involved... and it may be something with the order that dependencies are loaded.

I actually hit this in a more complicated app, trying to access the 'profile' property of my logged-in user (which exists, I promise).  It gives slightly different errors messages in different browsers; here's the stack trace in Chrome:

```
Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
    at Object.Template.workbook.owner (http://localhost:3000/client/client.js?153b3db62478692678dd9fdf9f1a9dd0b6b6a76e:130:21)
    at apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:276:24)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:301:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:365:30
    at Object.Spark.labelBranch (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1171:14)
    at branch (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:355:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:364:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?13ab483e8a3c795d9991577e65e811cd0b827997:130:11)
    at template (http://localhost:3000/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b:358:7) debug.js:41
Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Can't create second landmark in same branch
    at Object.Spark.createLandmark (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:1226:13)
    ...<snip>...
```

That last error about `Can't create second landmark in same branch` send me on a chase through other posts that all had to do with loops, but this is just a simple collection access.  There are some `forEach` calls in the stack trace, so I tried solutions like those in [Meteor issue 281](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/281), to no avail.

Hints and explanations of Meteor conventions are much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was experiencing this same issue.

```
return user && user.emails[0].address;
```

Checking if user is undefined first ( user && ... ) seems to have done it.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting up a race condition between the template being rendered and the data arriving from the server.

This is similar to expecting data to be available immediately after an async call; you have to wait for the callback to be executed to access the response.  In Meteor's case, since it takes some time to retrieve the data from the server, you have to ensure the expected fields have been populated before using them, as @landland suggests.

To explain the race condition further, most of the time your data arrives before the template is rendered and everything is fine.  But sometimes, the server hasn't finished publishing the user data to the client by the time the template renders so you get the error.  (This is what @jrullmann was describing in his comment.)

Also, since in your full app you are accessing a user different than your logged in one, you need to explicitly publish that user's information.  Only the currently logged-in user's info is auto-published by the Accounts packages.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Meteor user http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user

Meteor already provides the logged in user for you so you don't have to find him again.

Try

```
Template.hello.userData = function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  return user && user.emails[0].address;
};
```

Comment: Nope: this gives the same result, even in the test case I gave.  Further, this doesn't help me with my full application because I'm actually trying to access a user different from the one that is logged in.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this using the test case you gave with the simple test-user app using my suggested edit. Using your code as is, I was able to reproduce the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined" error. Are you sure you used the code changes I suggested? You shouldn't get the emails of undefined error if you are.

As for your help with your full application, you'll need to make sure you are publishing the users and do a findOne, but not with Meteor.userId() as in your OP, that won't work as that is the id of the logged in user.

Comment: Make sure your code is checking for the existence of the user before accessing a property, like landland's code example.  Even though the user may exist in the database it might not exist in the client collection yet, if the data hasn't finished loading when your template function is executed

Comment: @landland: Thank you!  I missed the conditional part of your code, and that indeed does the trick.  My apologies.  Thanks for everyone's comments on how this works.